# Python long format: subtract selection of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

All,

I have the following long format dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ["2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-02","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-02"], 'asset': ["x", "x","x", "x","y","y","y","y"], 'type': ["price", "spread","price","spread","price", "spread","price","spread"], 'value': ["1.5", "0.01","1.6", "0.01","1","0.08","1.2","0.09"]})
```

which looks like this:

```
         date asset    type value
0  2020-01-01     x   price   1.5
1  2020-01-01     x  spread  0.01
2  2020-01-02     x   price   1.6
3  2020-01-02     x  spread  0.01
4  2020-01-01     y   price     1
5  2020-01-01     y  spread  0.08
6  2020-01-02     y   price   1.2
7  2020-01-02     y  spread  0.09
```

I want to subtract the price of `y` from the price of `x` and maintain the same datastructure, result should should look like this:

```
         date    asset       type value
0  2020-01-01        x      price   1.5
1  2020-01-01        x     spread  0.01
2  2020-01-02        x      price   1.6
3  2020-01-02        x     spread  0.01
4  2020-01-01        y      price     1
5  2020-01-01        y     spread  0.08
6  2020-01-02        y      price   1.2
7  2020-01-02        y     spread  0.09
8  2020-01-01  x_min_y  pricediff   0.5
9  2020-01-02  x_min_y  pricediff   0.4
```

I would like to use the `assign()` function of pandas to create this but I am not sure how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pd.assign() is for adding new columns to your dataframe, it can't help you in adding new rows to your dataframe. You need to create the dataframe separating consisting of those 2 rows, and later use pd.concat() to assemble both

Comment: @Deepak You can use assign and then use melt() to maintain your long dataframe structure. But how do I use assign() and select the prices of x and y and subtract it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use:**

```
m = df['type'].eq('price') & df['asset'].isin(['x', 'y'])
d = df[m].pivot('date', 'asset', 'value').astype(float)

d = pd.concat(
    [df, d['x'].sub(d['y']).reset_index(name='value').assign(
        asset='x_min_y', type='pricediff')],
    ignore_index=True)
```

---

**Details:**

Create a boolean mask `m` to filter the rows where `type` is `price` and `asset` is in `x, y` and use [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to reshape the dataframe:

```
print(d) # pivoted dataframe
asset         x    y
date                
2020-01-01  1.5  1.0
2020-01-02  1.6  1.2
```

Use [`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) to subtract column `x` from `y` in the pivoted dataframe and assign the columns `asset` and `type`, then use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concat this pivoted dataframe with the original dataframe `df`.

```
print(d)
         date    asset       type value
0  2020-01-01        x      price   1.5
1  2020-01-01        x     spread  0.01
2  2020-01-02        x      price   1.6
3  2020-01-02        x     spread  0.01
4  2020-01-01        y      price     1
5  2020-01-01        y     spread  0.08
6  2020-01-02        y      price   1.2
7  2020-01-02        y     spread  0.09
8  2020-01-01  x_min_y  pricediff   0.5
9  2020-01-02  x_min_y  pricediff   0.4
```

Comment: that looks very promising, I just get the following error with the code:                 
        df.query("type == 'price' & asset.isin(['x', 'y'])")                                                                          TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: @JelleJansen Happy coding! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no need to match dates and that the dataset is defined as in the example, you can do the following:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1[df1["asset"] == "x" & df1["type"] == "price"]["value"].reset_index()["value"].astype(float)  - df1[df1["asset"] == "y" & df1["type"] == "price"]["value"].reset_index()["value"].astype(float))
df2["date"] = df1[df1["asset"] == "x"]["date"]
df2["type"] = df1[df1["asset"] == "x"]["type"]
df2["asset"] = "x_min_y"
pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

Basically, perform the calculations and concatenate afterwards

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this does not seem like efficient programming. I am looking for efficient syntax where I don't need to do a manipulation per column like you do but instead set it up in one line of code (which I am used to using R and R dplyr).